# c# VS 2019 Xamarin: Problem setting images source from code behind for embedded images

Tags: c#, image, xamarin

I have created an image in XAML successfully, within a grid, within AbsoulteLayout

```
<Image HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" 
   Source="{local:ImageResource ScKWander.Images.UI.arrow_pointer_R.png}"                
   TranslationY="330" TranslationX="15"
/>
```

I am trying to create images in code behind so I can change the positions in the code. While I have tried several possible alternatives, nothing has worked. The code below compiles and runs with no errors.  Catch is never hit, The only thing on the screen is the one image created in XAML.  I was only going to use the grid as a container, but I can use the grid row/col if its needed. In UWP, I was using a canvas.

I have tried several different ways of coding the source, but all have failed.  I took out all but the one.

I should add, I am getting several of Xamarin Errors now.  I think its the new build. I do not think those are affecting this. I build, run, and see one arrow defined by XAML.

```
private void FillGrid()
{
 int iYoffset   = 15;
 int iXoffset   = 15;
 int iYGridsize = 25;
 int iXGridsize = 25;
 try 
   {
   for (int iCount0 = 0; iCount0 < 5; iCount0++)
     {
     for (int iCount1 = 0; iCount1 < 5; iCount1++)
       {
         var thisImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource
            ("local:ImageResource ScKWander.Images.UI.arrow_pointer_R.png") };

       //thisImage.TranslationY  = iYoffset + (iCount0 * iYGridsize);
       //thisImage.TranslationX  = iXoffset + (iCount1 * iXGridsize);

         thisImage.HeightRequest = 25;
         thisImage.WidthRequest  = 25;
         gridBoard.Children.Add(thisImage, iCount0 * iYGridsize, iCount1 * iXGridsize);
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   string ex = e.Message;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, my real problem was not having:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

There was no IntelliType, but I finally found that this needed to be added.
Once that was done, the code below works.

```
var thisImage = new Image
{
  Source = ImageSource.FromResource(
    "ScKWander.Images.UI.arrow_pointer_r.png",
    typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
  ),
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images) shows exactly how to do this

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { 
  Source = ImageSource.FromResource(
    "WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", 
    typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
  ) };
```